# Rails and papaerclip uploading files to amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a Rails 4.2.1 application and want to upload a file with paperclip to amazon aws s3 cloud space.

Problem is aws is starting to log the uploadingen, but no file is written to s3.

**Model**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

 # add File to Movie association on column mo
 has_attached_file :movie,
                :storage => :s3,
                :bucket => 'xxx',
                :s3_credentials => {
                    :bucket => 'xxx',
                    :access_key_id => 'xxx',
                    :secret_access_key => 'xxx'
                }

  # validdates the file type
  validates_attachment_content_type :movie, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
end
```

**application.rb**

```
# Amazon S3 configuration for paperclip
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
}
```

**controller**

```
class MoviesController < ActionController::Base

  layout "application"

  # Method to add a new Movie
  def addMovie

    if request.post?
      #@movie = Movie.new(movies_params)
      @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
      if @movie.save
         redirect_to :addMovie
      end
     else
      @movie = Movie.new
    end

  end


  private

    def movies_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:movietitle, :movieprice, :locked, :moviedescription, :currency, :language, :movie)
  end
```

end

Has someone an idea whats going wrong?

Comment: I tried to use paperclip